# Fetching None with default value in dict

Tags: python

I have a dict with some value in it. Now at the time of fetching value I want to check if value is `None` replace it with `""`. Is there any single statement way for this.

```
a = {'x' : 1, 'y': None}
x = a.get('x', 3) # if x is not present init x with 3
z = a.get('z', 1) # Default value of z to 1
y = a.get('y', 1) # It will initialize y with None
# current solution I'm checking
if y is None:
    y = ""
```

What I want is something single line (pythonic way). I can do this in below way

```
# This is one way I can write but 
y = "" if a.get('y',"") is None else a.get('y', "")
```

But from what I know there must be some better way of doing this. Any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only falsy values you care about are `None` and `''`, you could do:

```
y = a.get('y', 1) or ''
```

Comment: This works if the value is guaranteed to be never 0.

Comment: Can you give me some insight on how it works as well. I mean `None or ''`. Why will `''` get assigned.

Comment: @PranjalDoshi `None` evaluates to `False` in a boolean test, so `or` will evaluate and return the second operand. See [here](https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/#default-values-for-variables) for a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 2):

[Jasmijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68737515/12975140) is very clean. If you need to accommodate other [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39983806/12975140) values *and* you insist on doing it in one line, you could use an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
y = "" if (initial := a.get('y', "")) is None else initial
```

But personally I would prefer your separate `if` check for clarity over this.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = a.get('y',"") or ""
```

Comment: This works if the value is guaranteed to be never 0.